# embedding graphical resources in .so file on Linux

Tags: linux, dll, resources, shared-libraries

I want create dynamic library(.so) on Linux that will draw pictures (png, bmp). I have found function **gtk_image_new_from_file()**.

But i don't want load images from file. I want load it from library resources.

Can i create dynamic library on Linux with some resource files (png, bmp) like dll on Windows?

Comment: thanks, i changed title.

Comment: This first idea that occurred to me is a static array that provides what your function call would return from a file image.  That Linux has traditionally *not* supported the resource fork (as MacOS does) is an [often raised issue](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/resource_forks.html).